# How to trigger rerender on test component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

I am testing this connected component:

```js
export class ExclusiveSelectboxesFormSectionView extends React.Component<Props> {
  handleSelection = (field: Field, message: string) => {
    this.props.setCard({ message, field });
  };
  cancelSelection = () => this.props.setCard({ message: null, field: null });

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.props.cancelTitle && (
          <CheckBox
            title={this.props.cancelTitle}
            checked={this.props.card.field == null}
            onPress={this.cancelSelection.bind(this)}
            checkedIcon="dot-circle-o"
            uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
          />
        )}
        {this.props.fields.map((field, i) => {
          const props = {};

          props.isSelected = this.props.card.field == field;
          props.selectionHandler = this.handleSelection.bind(this);

          return <ExclusiveFieldView field={field} key={i} {...props} />;
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapState = ({ currentFormReducer }) => {
  const card = currentFormReducer.card || { message: null, field: null };
  return { card };
};
const mapDispatch = { setCard };

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(ExclusiveSelectboxesFormSectionView);
```

I'm trying to test the non-connected component using `react-native-testing-library`. The component works in the app, but this test is failing to find `"Second field option 2"` in the next-to-last assertion in the test.

```js
// non-connected component
import { ExclusiveSelectboxesFormSectionView } from "../../src/components/ExclusiveSelectboxesFormSectionView";

function createWrapper(customProps) {
  let mockCard = { message: null, field: null };
  const props = {
    fields,
    setCard: jest.fn().mockImplementation((card: Types.Card) => {
      mockCard = card;
    }),
    card: mockCard,
    ...customProps
  };
  wrapper = render(
    <Fragment>
      <ExclusiveSelectboxesFormSectionView fields={fields} {...props} />
    </Fragment>
  );
  return wrapper;
}

describe("ExclusiveSelectboxesFormSectionView", () => {
  let checkboxes;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = createWrapper();
    checkboxes = wrapper.getAllByType(CheckBox);
    expect(checkboxes.length).toBe(3);
  });

  fit("shows the value of the currently selected field", async () => {
    await fireEvent.press(checkboxes[1]); // show options
    await fireEvent.press(wrapper.getByText("Second field option 2")); // select option

    const component = wrapper.getByType(ExclusiveSelectboxesFormSectionView);
    expect(component.props.setCard).toHaveBeenCalled();

    // options should be gone
    expect(wrapper.queryByText("Second field option 1")).toBeNull();
    // selected option should still be on screen
    expect(wrapper.getByText("Second field option 2")).toBeDefined();
    expect(checkboxes[1].props.checked).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

I've passed in a `card` prop and a `setCard` mock function prop, in place of redux providing these.

The mock `setCard` function is being called, so I think the problem is that the component is not rerendering with its new props (and a newly set `card` prop). A log statement in the component's render function confirms this (it only prints once when the test is run).

I imagine there's something basic I'm missing about how I'm rendering the component, or wrapping it, or calling it, or something.

Can anyone spot my problem?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `react-native-testing-library`'s `update` function does the trick. But it was a bit tough to figure out.

```js
// refactored from createWrapper
function getWrapperProps() {
  return {
    fields,
    setCard: jest.fn().mockImplementation((card: Types.Card) => {
      mockCard = card;
    }),
    card: mockCard
  };
}

function createWrapper(customProps) {
  wrapper = render(
    <Fragment>
      <ExclusiveSelectboxesFormSectionView
        {...getWrapperProps()}
        {...customProps}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
  return wrapper;
}

function updateWrapper(customProps) {
  wrapper.update(
    <Fragment>
      <ExclusiveSelectboxesFormSectionView
        {...getWrapperProps()}
        {...customProps}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
  checkboxes = wrapper.getAllByType(CheckBox);
}

// call updateWrapper() when you need to get the newly rendered props
  it("shows the value of the currently selected field", async () => {
    await fireEvent.press(checkboxes[1]);
    await fireEvent.press(wrapper.getByText("Second field option 2"));

    const component = wrapper.getByType(ExclusiveSelectboxesFormSectionView);
    expect(component.props.setCard).toHaveBeenCalled();

    updateWrapper();

    // options should be gone
    expect(wrapper.queryByText("Second field option 1")).toBeNull();
    // selected option should still be on screen
    expect(wrapper.getByText("Second field option 2")).toBeDefined();
    expect(checkboxes[1].props.checked).toBe(true);
  });
```

Now it passes.

I'd love to know of other options. I'm not clear why this had been working with an earlier implementation, although the earlier implementation used `state` in the component, which I'm sure is basically *the* answer.